# Use of v-model and v-for with array in Vuex state

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building the tabs for a tabbed interface, in which the user can change the titles of the tabs. What I'd like to do is something like this:

Markup:

```
<div class="tabs" v-for="(tab, tabIndex) in tabs" :key="tab.id" >
  <input type="text" v-model:value="tabs(tabIndex)">
</div>
```

Computed property:

```
computed: {
  scenes2: {
    get(tabIndex){
      return this.$store.state.tabs[tabIndex].title
    },
    set(value, tabIndex){
      this.$store.dispatch('setTabTitle', {value: value, tabIndex: tabIndex} )
    },
  },
},
```

This doesn't work, of course. What is the proper way to use v-model here so that I can correlate the `v-model` with the relevant index on the `tabs` array in the Vuex state?

Answer (score 11):

I wouldn't use computed properties with arrays and objects.

```
 <div class="tabs" v-for="(tab, tabIndex) in $store.state.tabs" :key="tab.id">
   <input type="text" :value="tab.title" @input="e => updateTabTitle(tabIndex, e)">
 </div>

methods: {
  updateTabTitle(tabIndex, event) {
    this.$store.dispatch('setTabTitle', {value: event.target.value, tabIndex} )
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Is is *possible* to do with with v-model? Is there a case where that's preferred?

Comment: Maybe with a local copy of the tabs array (in data) and then a deep watcher on this array to dispatch the changes (of the whole array)